# Is there a way to install esxi on a system you want to virtualize?

Tags: virtualization

I don't have extra hardware.  Is it possible to install ESXi so that it virtualizes the previous OS that was on the system?  If so, can someone point me to the documentation?  My google-fu is weak.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really.

What I would do is use VMware vCenter Converter to P2V the virtual machine to an external drive or network share, (by selecting **VMware Workstation or other VMware virtual machine** as the destination) detach the disk, then install ESXi on the server and import the VM that was created with vCenter Converter.

Comment: +1 This was the exact same anwser i was just writing!

Comment: Sigh.  I would have really liked this to be effortless, but I guess it's not so bad.

Comment: That's about as close to effortless as it's going to get. And it's really not bad. You would have had to P2V it anyway, regardless.